# Find Last 10 authors for a certain file in Git

Tags: git, version-control, project-management

What is the best (from performance point of view) way to find in Git the last 10 users who changed a certain file ?

For example I want to know the last 10 committers (not the last 10 commits) of file foo.txt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd try something like this in *nix systems (w/ bash)

```
git log --format=%an foo.txt |awk ' !x[$0]++' |head -10
```

Comment: uniq on not sorted rows produces duplicates, and sorting destroys order of authors

Comment: @astropanic You're right, I replaced uniq with awk. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The grep can be optimized away: `git log --pretty=%an | awk ' !x[$0]++' | head -n 10`. Also, I really need to learn awk.

Comment: +1 for the `awk` magic! You should use `git log --format=%an -- foo.txt` to remove the extra grep, though, as @astronpanic suggests...